# How can a non-owner come to an apartment

Tags: internal-consistency

Let's say you're a killer, sitting in your client's apartment, waiting for your client. Surprisingly to you, the entrance door opens and another person comes in. An old man, whose life story is a sequence of missed opportunities. So now you have to kill him as well, not to leave any witnesses of your presence there. The question is: how could this person appear in this apartment?

For example, the situation where the old man is the owner who came to check on the apartment where his tenant (killer's client) lives does not really fit, as a person with a life story of missed opportunities is unlikely to own an apartment (unless it's a very bad one). I think that can be modified into the old man being a plumber in this apartment house, or whatever tradesman attached to it who takes care of leakages etc.

Any other ideas? Feel free to retag.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Ilya*! This question looks very opinion-based to me. How are we supposed to judge answers? What makes "He's a plumber" better than "He is the poor cousin who is allowed to stay" better than "He's a poor guy who found the reserve key under the doormat" better than ...? Can you [edit] this question to show objective criteria for what makes an answer better than another answer? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it seems that I mostly asked for alternative explanations, and even your comment already gave quite some. Could you also suggest how to objectify the question? For example, I can ask - what is the most boring and simple explanation that fits all the setting of the story that I've given, would that be enough?

Comment: Sadly "boring" is a very subjective term. You are the only one to judge what is "boring" for you and what is not. 
I will think about what could make this less opinion-based, but actions of a character are in general off-topic
because they are inherently opinion-based. It depends on what makes sense for your story and so you are the 
only own who can judge whether some action makes sense. Why he walks into this house seems to me to be such
an action of a character. For example: do you need him to be a plumber for a certain story? Could the client have just forgotten to lock the door?...

Comment: @Secespitus: no, I don't need anything from him, rather than just being a loser who also appears in the wrong place in the wrong time. You'd think such a question would be an off-topic, right?

Comment: This is not world building... this is idea generation for a story. Also, did this really need to be asked? Cleaning-service, friend that feeds the fishes/picks up or leaves an item/gathers the mail, secret lover, building maintenance, burglar... the possibilities are near endless.

Comment: "a person with a life story of missed opportunities is unlikely to own an apartment" - I wouldn't say that - he may be an *Accidental Landlord*. i.e. he was conned  into buying an apartment by a bank in the early noughties "boom time", but has since fallen on hard times and due to the recession, couldn't sell it and is now forced to rent it out just to keep up repayments. This actually happened to quite a few people (in Ireland anyway)

Comment: @Ilya It does look off-topic, to me and it appears to quite some other users, too. This does look like an "Element of plot"/actions of a character opposed to building an element of a world in which your story plays, which is off-topic when looking at the list of [What topics can I ask about here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If it's really unimportant, why not go with the situation that is most likely from the perspective of your client? Is he forgetful and didn't lock the door? Does he have a lover? A close friend? Neighbours who visit? Does he rescue others? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Some sort of contractor who is trusted enough to have the keys. Cleaning staff, to give one big example. The old lady/gentleman who comes every week.
- Some friend who does services while the owner is away. Feeding the cat, watering the plants, sorting the mail and forwarding important/unexpected ones.
- Some friend who is allowed to stay overnight.